# correct way to define this profile information in bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an image attached with how I would like a list of profile information to be set out in this particular way: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kALXa.jpg

This list is suppose to grab data from a database, and place the information to the right of the labels in the attached image.

I thought of doing a definition list so the dt is the label and the dd is the information from the database, but that's probably not semantically correct to use a definition list?

I am stumped on what this information should look like, or what the proper way should be?

I added some code, thinking of a description list, but the code isnt really working properly :/ and a definition list is probably not the way to go??

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 center-block">
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
          <dt>heading</dt>
          <dd>
            <button class="btn btn-default"></button>
          </dd>

          <dt>another heading</dt>
          <dd>
            <button class="btn btn-default"></button>
          </dd>

          <dt>another heading</dt>
          <dd>
            <button class="btn btn-default"></button>
          </dd>

          <dt>another heading</dt>
          <dd>
            <button class="btn btn-default"></button>
          </dd>

          <dt>another heading</dt>
          <dd>
            <button class="btn btn-default"></button>
          </dd>
        </dl>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple just use the bootstrap grid system. Put your server side code at appropriate place.

```css
body{margin:10px;}
.profile{width:100%;height:auto;}
.name{font-size:40px;}
.row{margin-top:5px;}
```

```html
<head>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="name">
        <span>First Name</span>
        <span> Last Name</span>
        <button class="btn btn-default pull-right">Button</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">

        <img src="http://images6.fanpop.com/image/photos/38400000/Stylish-Boy-emo-boys-38433361-1946-3107.jpg" class="imag-responsive profile" >
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4"><label>heading</label></div>
          <div class="col-xs-8"><button class="btn btn-default">Button</button></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4"><label>another heading</label></div>
          <div class="col-xs-8"><img src="http://listaka.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/baby-boy-wearing-hat.jpg" width=100px height=100px></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4"><label>another heading</label></div>
          <div class="col-xs-8">decription of Heading</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4"><label>another heading</label></div>
          <div class="col-xs-8">Date</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4"><label>another heading</label></div>
          <div class="col-xs-8">175 cm</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4"><label>another heading</label></div>
          <div class="col-xs-8">soccer,hockey,Baseball</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4"><label>another heading</label></div>
          <div class="col-xs-8">Some another decription</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: How do I make this responsive??

Answer (score -1):

Read bootstrap documentation carefully.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

You'll get solution :)

Comment: what do you propose I should implement instead of the list?